# What spinoff technologies have come from the Soviet/Russian space program?

Tags: russia, spinoff

There is plenty of information available on NASA spinoff technologies including a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_spinoff_technologies) and [Space SE question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/411/what-are-the-everyday-technologies-that-are-a-byproduct-of-the-apollo-program). What innovations are a byproduct of the Russian space program?

Comment: I think the whole anti-capitalist communism thing and fall of the USSR really hurt their ability to commercialize much of their achievements made early on. If you think about it, the whole period from the 1960's to early 2000s was not very conducive for advancements in the private sector.